# AnyDice: Second highest roll from mixed pool

Tags: anydice

I'm struggling to adapt Ilmari Karonen's answers from these [two](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96002/how-can-i-get-the-highest-two-die-rolls-from-a-mixed-pool-in-anydice) [questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63651/how-should-i-emulate-the-highest-in-an-irregular-dice-pool-in-anydice/63661#63661) to my problem.

I want to look at the second highest value from various pools.

```
function: max A:n B:n C:n {
    result: 2@[sort {A, B, C}]
}
output [max 1d12 1d10 1d8]
```

Produces possibly believable results, but:

```
output [max 2d12 0d10 0d8]
```

Is not at all believable, and completely disagrees with:

```
output 2@2d12
```

Similarly testing with

```
function: maxs A:n {
    result: 2@[sort {A}]
}
output [maxs 2d12]
```

hasn't helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were pretty close — all you needed was to replace the `:n` type specifiers with `:s`, so that your dice rolls will be passed to the function as sequences, instead of being summed into single numbers, [like this](https://anydice.com/program/1b25b):

```
function: second highest of A:s B:s C:s {
    result: 2@[sort {A, B, C}]
}
output [second highest of 1d12 1d10 1d8]
```

In fact, you might as well [generalize this function](https://anydice.com/program/1b25d) into:

```
function: P:s at A:s B:s C:s {
    result: P@[sort {A, B, C}]
}
output [2 at 1d12 1d10 1d8]
```

which works just like the built-in `@` operator, except that it can take multiple dice pools on the right hand side and merge them before selecting (and summing) one or more positions.

Answer (score 4):

Just played around with it (never used AnyDice before) and it looks like the problem is with what you think is in your groups.

```
function: max A:n B:n C:n {
result: 2@[sort {A, B, C}]
}
output [max 2d12 0d10 0d8]
```

Gives us a set A = d12 + d12 (range of 2 to 24) but we're sorting the 3 sets (A,B,C) not the individual dice so in first position is d12+d12 but second position would always be 0 because you've rolled B or C 0 times.

If you use:

```
function: max A:n B:n C:n {
result: 2@[sort {A, B, C}]
}
output [max 1d12 1d12 0d8]
```

You get the right answer because set B is now a d12 too.