# AnyDice: Nested highest/lowest function

Tags: anydice

I understand how to keep highest or lowest die every time:

```
\ Keep highest \
output 1@2d6 + 1d6
output [highest 1 of 2d6] + 1d6

\ Keep lowest \
output 2@2d6 + 1d6
output [lowest 1 of 2d6] + 1d6
```

but how can I take lowest then highest?

Something incorrect happens under the hood when I perform either of the following:

```
\ Keep lowest then highest \
output 1@(2@2d6 + 1d6) + 1d6
output [highest 1 of ([lowest 1 of 2d6] + 1d6)]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't merge two separate dice into one pool in AnyDice.  However, the built-in `[highest of NUMBER and NUMBER]` function will [work just fine on two dice](https://anydice.com/program/26caf):

```
\ Keep lowest then highest \
output [highest of [lowest 1 of 2d6] and d6]
output [highest of 2@2d6 and d6]
```

---

**Ps.** If you happened to have *more* than two separate dice that you wanted to take the highest of, you could either nest the functions, e.g. [like this](https://anydice.com/program/26cb3):

```
output [highest of [highest of d8 and d6] and d4]
```

or write your own function, e.g. like in [one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63651/how-should-i-emulate-the-highest-in-an-irregular-dice-pool-in-anydice/63661#63661) of [these](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96002/how-can-i-get-the-highest-two-die-rolls-from-a-mixed-pool-in-anydice/96046#96046) earlier [answers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/168048/anydice-second-highest-roll-from-mixed-pool/168054#168054) of mine.  The last one of those gives [a particularly general solution](https://anydice.com/program/26cb9), which works just like the AnyDice `@` operator except that it can take multiple pools of dice as parameters:

```
function: P:s at A:s B:s C:s {
    result: P@[sort {A, B, C}]
}

output [1 at 3d4 2d6 1d8] named "highest"
output [6 at 3d4 2d6 1d8] named "lowest"
output [{1,6} at 3d4 2d6 1d8] named "highest + lowest"
```

(If you need more than three different dice pools, just add more parameters to the function.  If you want to use the same function for *fewer* pools than the number of parameters it takes, you can use `{}` as a placeholder to represent a pool of zero dice.)